# I used a multimedia ppa and now vlc is broken

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, vlc

I used this ppa, https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/xerus-media 
and to be fair it said it may conflict, but I was trying to do something else, and thought it could help me, so I installed, and used it anyhow.

But VLC is broken, and I want to use it. I tried purging the PPA, and reinstalling vlc, but vlc remains broken.

When I try to use it, I get messages like this:

```
$ cvlc Reel\ 2\ Real\ -\ I\ Like\ To\ Move\ It\ \(Rob\ \&\ Chris\ Bootleg\)\ \(Bass\ Boosted\)\ \[720p\].mp4 
VLC media player 2.2.8 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.7-14-g3cc1d8cba9)
[0000000001b21218] core input error: open of `file/xspf-open:///home/$USER/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' failed
[0000000001b21218] core input error: Your input can't be opened
[0000000001b21218] core input error: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file/xspf-open:///home/$USER/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'. Check the log for details.
[0000000001b34548] core audio output error: no suitable audio output module
[0000000001b36048] core interface error: no suitable interface module
[0000000001b07148] core libvlc error: interface "hotkeys,none" initialization failed
[0000000001b36048] core interface error: no suitable interface module
[0000000001b07148] core libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[0000000001b36048] core interface error: no suitable interface module
[0000000001b07148] core libvlc error: interface "dbus,none" initialization failed
[0000000001b36048] core interface error: no suitable interface module
[0000000001b07148] core libvlc error: interface "default" initialization failed
[0000000001b1ee68] core playlist error: could not export playlist
```

So... what should I do to fix vlc?

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove vlc --purge`, then `sudo apt-get autoremove`, then `sudo apt-get clean`. Then try re-installing vlc again.

Comment: I tried moving the $HOME/.local/share/vlc file, and purge autoremove, clean, those things did not work. maybe i can try installing from source.  so it says lua is not installed, I tried installing lua, but it doesnt help. I tried installing the specific version VLC looks for, and the vlc configure script still fails. ... what a pain.

Comment: So I got to place where I couldnt find the protoc compiler? so i modified the vlc configure script to skip that.  but make is jaming up on some chromecast nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

Move your vlc configuration away using this command:

```
mv $HOME/.local/share/vlc $HOME/.local/share/vlc.bak
```

Then try again.